# Extjs Anchor Layout using offsets

Tags: extjs

What is the offset configuration actually doing that makes panel 2 to show incompletely when the panel 1 is resized vertically?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        height      : 300,
        width       : 300,
        layout      : 'anchor',
        border      : false,
        anchorSize  : 400,
        items       : [
            {
                title : 'panel 1',
                anchor: '-50, -150',
                frame : true
            },
            {
                title : 'panel 2',
                anchor: '-10, -150', // how is this config working?
                frame : true
            }
        ]
    });
    myWin.show();
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/64r

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is from ExtJs in Action second edition page 96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from ExtJS docs...

```
// two values specified
    anchor: '-50 -100' // render item the complete width of the container
                       // minus 50 pixels and
                       // the complete height minus 100 pixels.
    // one value specified
    anchor: '-50'      // anchor value is assumed to be the right offset value
                       // bottom offset will default to 0
```

So possibly you're resizing the window to a size smaller than 150 (that is 300 - the specified anchor) pixels.. so "the complete height minus 150 pixels" will actually result in cropping of the item inside that container.

It would be much better to see some example of what you're trying to achieve and a fiddle of how it's working now though.

**EDIT**

You're setting the height of both components to be "the size of the window" minus some fixed amount (50) of pixels. If the window grows to 500 pixels "tall" then you get two panels that are 450 pixels tall. That's why the second panel always overflows the window.

It's all in the portion of docs that I posted earlier though. You may want to try some other layouts too, maybe nested layouts, for example: an `anchor` layout inside an `hbox` layout.

Comment: I am resizing to a greater height actually.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.create("Ext.Window", ({
height : 300,
width : 300,   items : [
    {
    title : 'Panel1',
    anchor : '-50, -150',
    frame : true
    },
    {
    title : 'Panel2',
    anchor : '-10, -150',
    frame : true
    }
    ]

}));
```

Panel1 Width = 288px - 50px = 238px

Panel1 Height = 285px - 150px = 135px

Panel2 Width = 288px - 10px = 278px

Panel2 Height = 285px - 150px = 135px